# Gradle does not find property for Properties file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have run into this problem when I wanted to make a **release** build of my android app. This worked fine a couple of days ago but now it dosnt seem to work for some reason. I haven't touched the file gradle file except for adding the second compile dependancie for Picasso lib. The properties file hasn't been changed and neither the keystore.

This is what I get whe trying to build.

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\'\C:\Users\MyName\Documents\keystores\android.keystore'' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig
    }
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.happymtb.unofficial"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 17
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = file('../signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {

        android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        android.buildTypes.releaseConfig.signingConfig = null
    }
}else {
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
```

**signing.properties**

```
STORE_FILE='//C:/Users/MyName/Documents/keystores/android.keystore'
STORE_PASSWORD='passw'
KEY_ALIAS='myalias'
KEY_PASSWORD='passw'
```

Comment: You can use STORE_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/Documents/keystores/android.keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by updating all the libs. Cleanung/rebuilding the project alot of times and changing **signing.properties** file to this (basically removing all **'**):

```
STORE_FILE=//C:/Users/MyName/Documents/keystores/android.keystore
STORE_PASSWORD=passw
KEY_ALIAS=myalias
KEY_PASSWORD=passw
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the signing properties file in the same directory as build gradle file (this is simil;ar to gradle properties file).

Comment: That is not needed. The problem is not with the signing.properties file.

Comment: It is not true. You can put the signing file everywhere

Answer (score 0):

The gradle look to you root project, try to move your **signing.properties** to your root folder